# Add arraylist to listadapter to let it display on listview,but i get error with that

Tags: android

I face problem to add the String array inside a arraylist that is use to insert inside listview,my string array called ChecklistData

Main Activity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

ArrayList<Product> products = new ArrayList<Product>();

ListAdapter boxAdapter;


  /** Called when the activity is first created. */
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.listview);
    fillData();
    boxAdapter = new ListAdapter(this, products);

    ListView lvMain = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvMain);
    lvMain.setAdapter(boxAdapter);
  }

  void fillData() {




      for(int i=1;i<=20;i++)
      {
          products.add(getResources().getString(R.array.ChecklistData));
      }

  }

  public void showResult(View v) {
    String result = "Selected Product are :";
    int totalAmount=0;
    for (Product p : boxAdapter.getBox()) {
      if (p.box){
        result += "\n" + p.name;
        totalAmount+=p.price;
      }
    }
    Toast.makeText(this, result+"\n"+"Total Amount:="+totalAmount, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  }
}
```

person class that use for accept string array

```
public class Product {
String name[];





public String[] getName() {
    return name;
}


public void setName(String[] name) {
    this.name = name;
}




Product(String[] name) {
    this.name = name;

  }
}
```

the listadapter that use to add the arraylist into listview

```
 public class ListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
Context ctx;
LayoutInflater lInflater;
ArrayList<Product> objects;

ListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Product> products) {
    ctx = context;
    objects = products;
    lInflater = (LayoutInflater) ctx
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return objects.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return objects.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = convertView;
    if (view == null) {
        view = lInflater.inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);
    }

    Product p = getProduct(position);

    ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvDescr)).setText(p.name);
    ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvPrice)).setText(p.price + "");
    ((ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.ivImage)).setImageResource(p.image);

    CheckBox cbBuy = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.cbBox);
    cbBuy.setOnCheckedChangeListener(myCheckChangList);
    cbBuy.setTag(position);
    cbBuy.setChecked(p.box);
    return view;
}

Product getProduct(int position) {
    return ((Product) getItem(position));
}

ArrayList<Product> getBox() {
    ArrayList<Product> box = new ArrayList<Product>();
    for (Product p : objects) {
        if (p.box)
            box.add(p);
    }
    return box;
}

OnCheckedChangeListener myCheckChangList = new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
            boolean isChecked) {
        getProduct((Integer) buttonView.getTag()).box = isChecked;
    }
};
```

}

Comment: What was the exact error in it? is that my constructor in product class define wrongly or my way to add the string array into arraylist was wrong? if wrong please fix me

Comment: Show us your logcat result we can not figure out error like this as it will take long time to read the whole code..

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to do

```
products.add(getResources().getString(R.array.ChecklistData));
```

which i think is you are trying to add a `string array` to a `Product ArrayList` which is not possible.

If `ChecklistData` is a `string array` then you need to get it by

```
getResources().getStringArray(R.array.ChecklistData)
```

iterate through it and add the `String` to the `Product ArrayList` something like

```
String[] dataArray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.ChecklistData);

for(String productName : dataArray)
{
  products.add(new Product(productName));
}
```